# I am suddenly getting a NET::ReadTimeout On Visit with Pageobjects/Watir/Ruby

Tags: ruby, cucumber, watir, pageobjects, page-object-gem

I have a very stable Pageobjects/Watir/Ruby/Cucumber framework.
It is still working fine executing through Jenkins/Browserstack, and Browserstack Local from my machine.
Other co-workers are  not getting this issue.

On the visit step, I am getting `Net::ReadTimeout: Net::ReadTimeout`.
The IDE is reporting the failure on the Visit line in the Cucumber step file.

The browser is launching and going to the correct page for the specified page object.
This has been observed in both Chrome and Firefox. (I am on a Mac)

Nothing I have seen in Google looks close to my issue.
I am at a loss.

Comment: So when does the issue happen?  When you aren't using browserstack?

Comment: It's happening because your page loads happens for more than 60 sec after a click. Just check it right or not.

Comment: @Jason : I guess, i noticed the same error too earlier. Can you please paste the whole error logs?

Comment: Try adding a sleep command and check?

Comment: @orde, yes, it happens when I am running locally on a local Browser.

Comment: @Mrityunjeyan, I dont have any more error log then what I posted. that is part of what has me stumped. This is all happening within the Visit command.  I cannot insert a sleep.

Comment: @JasonKoelewyn There is either a problem with the existing session of watir and the browser's driver or it could be since, the website is still loading more than the default wait time, and the next step cannot be processed. Can you shut down the `browser's driver` and again restart it? then check? Also, it would be nice, if you can mention what is your code and when you are getting this error.

Comment: @JasonKoelewyn You haven't read my reply. It's happening because some of your click loads the page more than 60 secs. It crosses the default time.

Comment: @RAJ, I did read your reply.  What does not make sense there is it only happens locally.  If it was slow loading I would expect it to occur on Browserstack as well, esp since performance is noticeably worse on BS.

Comment: @MrityunjeyanS, the code is visit(AppHelpers.get_page_name($page, 'page_object')).await     visit is an method of the Page Objects gem. If your assumption is correct, do you know of a fix?

Comment: @JasonKoelewyn I met this problem and I found a work around as well. Just increase the time to 300 seconds and it would work.

Comment: @RAJ, it is occurring within a gem method.  I have tried increasing the global timeout with Watir.default_timeout = 90 to no effect.  I actually suspect something is wrong on my machine.  But full shut downs and cache clears do not seem to help.

Comment: `Watir.default_timeout = 90` is for element to exist not for loading after the click.

Comment: @RAJ     
So where do you set the timeout?

Comment: @JasonKoelewyn prototype file!